# Function Analysis

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

[image: This is a problem I Found on the Internet]

I tried to differentiate the function and set the value at =0 in order to find x in terms of a and b. Then, I also tried to plug the value of x into in and set the value of y into 1 and 4. At the end, I was struggling since it became more tedious. So anyone can suggest a nicer way to solve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution which is a little bit tedious but less than some of the others.

The equation $f(x)=1$ is equivalent to:
\begin{align*}
    ax^2 + 4x + b &= x^2 + 2
\\\iff (a-1)x^2 + 4x + (b-2) &= 0
\end{align*}
This is a quadratic equation in $x$.  If $f$ has a minimum at $x$ too, then we can assume the equation has one double solution.  Therefore the discriminant of the quadratic polynomial must be zero:
\begin{align*}
    0 &= 4^2 - 4(a-1)(b-2) = 4(2a+b + 2 - ab)
\end{align*}
In a similar way, the equation $f(x) = 4$ gives
\begin{align*}
    ax^2 + 4x + b &= 4(x^2 + 2)
\\\iff (a-4)x^2 + 4x + (b-8) &= 0
\end{align*}
Since $4$ is the maximum value, we expect a double solution, so the discriminant is zero as well:
\begin{align*}
    0 &= 4^2 - 4(a-4)(b-8) = 4(8a+4b - 28 - ab)
\end{align*}
Putting these together, we have two equations in the two unknowns $a$ and $b$:
\begin{align*}
    2a+b - ab &= -2 \tag{1}
\\  8a + 4b - ab &=28 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Subtracting ($1$) from ($2$) gives
$$
    6a+3b = 30 \implies 2a+b = 10 \tag{3}
$$
Subtracting $4$ times ($1$) from ($2$) gives
$$
    3ab = 36 \implies ab = 12 \tag{4}
$$
We can substitute ($3$) into ($4$) to get
\begin{align*}
    a(10-2a) = 12 \implies
    a^2 - 5a + 6 = 0 
\end{align*}
The solutions are $a = 2$ (yielding $b=6$) and $a=3$ (yielding $b=4$).

Comment: So you're assuming  there is only 1 value of x representing the extremes since this kind of rational function would have only 1 maximum point and 1 minimum point (or 1 stationary on each), right? I think this is the best solution that one can create. Excellent! Thank You :)

Comment: @curious_dino That's right.  I suppose you could have two distinct solutions with one a local maximum and one not a critical point.  But the problem says “*the* maximum” so we could rule that out.  I'd like a method that explicitly used $f'(x) = 0$ when $f(x) =1$ but it's pretty hairy.

Comment: Thank you. It helps a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

**HINTS**

The only way I could get through the tedium was using wolfram. I solved the problem as follows.

You have two equations

$\quad f(x) = 4 \text{ and } f'(x) = 0$

in three variables, $a$, $b$ and $x$.

So attempt to eliminate $a$ or $b$ and when you do you'll find that $b$ can be expressed in terms of $a$,

$\tag 1 b = \frac{4 (2 a - 7)}{a - 4}$

Use [Wolfram Step 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%28ax%5E2%2B4x%2Bb%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B2%29%3D4%5D%20and%20%20%5Bderivative%20%28ax%5E2%2B4x%2Bb%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B2%29%3D0%5D%20) which solves for $b$.

After a copy-paste, you have two equations,

$\quad f(x) = 1 \text{ and } f'(x) = 0$

in two variables, $a$ and $x$.

Here you'll get to choose between two $a,x$ solutions and only one will work.

Use [Wolfram Step 2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%28ax%5E2%2B4x%2B%5Cfrac%7B4%20%282%20a%20-%207%29%7D%7Ba%20-%204%7D%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B2%29%3D1%5D%20and%20%20%5Bderivative%20%28ax%5E2%2B4x%2B%5Cfrac%7B4%20%282%20a%20-%207%29%7D%7Ba%20-%204%7D%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B2%29%3D0%5D%20) which solves for $a$ and $x$.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It is still hard without any help of wolfram alpha here indeed since the structure is quite complicated & I really tried to solve it without using it.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to use the wolfram alpha in order to solve this problem using your method mentioned above?

Answer (score 3):

$$\text{max}\big\{f(x) \big\} = \frac{2a+b+\sqrt{32 + (b-2a)^2}}{4} \qquad 
\text{min}\big\{f(x) \big\} = \frac{2a+b-\sqrt{32 + (b-2a)^2}}{4}$$

So either $a = 3$ and $b = 4$ or $a = 2$ and $b = 6$.

Comment: I'm tempted to delete my answer since your approach uses the equations in a more tactical manner. (+1)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But how do you get those equations?

Comment: @curious_dino I just worked through the tedious part.

Comment: thankyou :) @Christian

Comment: @Christian After finding the root x in terms of a and b (from f'(x) = 0), I tried to compute the tedious work using that value of x into the function. but even wolfram alpha was unable to do it. Do you use wolfram alpha premium or not? thanks

Comment: I don't have premium. It worked with https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+%28ax%5E2%2B4x%2Bb%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B2%29+where+x%3D%282a-b%2Bsqrt%2832%2B4a%5E2-4ab%2Bb%5E2%29%29%2F4 . You could also type "maximize (ax^2+4x+b)/(x^2+2)".

Comment: thank you so much :) @Christian